# Server X / NVidia Fatal Error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, crash

I have a GTX 1050 and installed the proprietary driver of Nvidia 435 from Sofware & updates and I got several times a crash of the X Server.

I got these logs from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Hewlett_Packard_HP_23cw_6CM536104Z_adam_1000
Jan 26 22:28:44 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB org.gnome.Shell.desktop[30551]: [2190:2505:0126/222844.506360:FATAL:bus.cc(1215)] D-Bus connection was disconnected. Aborting.
Jan 26 22:28:44 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB gnome-shell[30551]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Jan 26 22:28:44 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB firefox[22692]: firefox: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Jan 26 22:28:44 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB vmware-player.desktop[25652]: XINFO IO fatal error.
Jan 26 22:28:44 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB org.gnome.Shell.desktop[30551]: [2353:2353:0126/222844.930995:ERROR:x11_util.cc(110)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Jan 26 22:28:44 adam-Lenovo-YOGA-720-15IKB wine-Programs-WinSCP.desktop[5166]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server ":0"
```

How to know what has crashed and has caused the crash of the server X?

Comment: Well, since these crashes started occurring when you installed the proprietary driver, the answer to your question is likely: It's the new driver which has caused the crash of the X server. You appear to be looking for some X client application as the culprit, but a client should not be able to crash the server; if it does, something is likely wrong with the server. Looking at the X server logs (`/var/log/Xorg.*`) may provide some more insights, but if the proprietary drivers are at fault, there may not be a lot you can do about it.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I should have specified that I installed the proprietary driver just after having installed Ubuntu 18. So I am using it since the beginning. I don't find any dates in the Xorg log file and no error in it. Before crashing, I can hear that the PC is high charged with the fan running full throttle, the mouse almost doesn't move and I cannot change the selected window.